# difficulty with outputting strings correctly from array?

Tags: c

I'm making a program that takes in one format of a date from the user, such as: "01/14/2013" as a string and outputs it into the month, day and year format, or: "January 14,2013". I can't figure out why it isn't outputting the string correctly when I enter the date, for example if I type in '01', it outputs January correctly, but if i type in '02', it doesn't print out February correctly at all. Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) //int main() is c++, int main(void) is C
{ 
  char date[100]; 
  char month[100]; 
  char array[12][100] ={"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",
                      "December"};

  printf(" Please enter a date "); 
  fgets( date, 100, stdin); 

  if( date[0] == '0' && date[1] == '1')
  {
    strcpy( month, array[0]); 
  }
  else if( date [0] =='0' && date[1] == '2')
  { 
    strcpy( month, array[1]);
  }   

  printf(" %s", month); 

  return 0; 

}
```

Comment: I tested it on my machine, and it does print `February` correctly.

Comment: In you question, you need to fix the extra brace and semicolon here `"November", "December"}; };` I also get `February` just fine.

Comment: `int main()` is valid C

Answer (score 0):

While you can set up an elaborate parse routing to handle dates in a custom way. You can also make use of `strptime` to convert a string into a date object, and then use `strftime` to output the string to a buffer in any format you desire. The `man pages` contain all the format specifiers and examples which I've adapted to your situation. Take a look:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct tm tm;
    char buf[255];

    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input, usage: %s date (mm/dd/yyyy)\n",
                 argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
    strptime(argv[1], "%m/%d/%Y", &tm);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%A, %B %e, %Y", &tm);
    printf ("\n  The formatted date is:  %s\n\n",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Just enter any date on the command line in `mm/dd/yyyy` format and it outputs similar to what you were looking for:

```
$ ./bin/s2t 07/08/2014

The formatted date is:  Tuesday, July  8, 2014
```